# Why presheaf is a contravariant functor?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I'm following the discussion from [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivation+for+sheaves%2C+cohomology+and+higher+stacks).

> If you give me a map $U \stackrel{f}{\to} V$ from one test space to
>   another, then for any element $V \stackrel{p}{\to} X$ of $X(V)$, I can
>   produce an element $U \stackrel{f}{\to} V \stackrel{p}{\to} X$ of
>   $X(U)$. In other words, your map $U \to V$ induces a transformation
>   $X(U) \leftarrow X(V)$.

I can't get, why it induces map $X(U) \leftarrow X(V)$ and not $X(U) \rightarrow X(V)$ ?

I thought that this map would produce functorial diagram like that

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>{f}>> V;\\
@VVV @VVV \\
X(U) @>{X(f)}>> X(V);
\end{CD}
$$
but that seems not to be the case. What's the idea behind reverse morphism arrows?

Comment: $X$ is not a map from $V$ to $X(V)$ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! and the idea is explained in the quote you showed

Comment: @mercio I know that $X$ is a functor and not a map, I just don't know how to draw functorial diagrams correctly here. Though, I still don't understand explanation given in quote.

Comment: when you say "commutative diagram" it implies that you think that you can actually compose $f$ with $X$ to get some $f \circ X$, which is very, very, very very wrong. If "for any element of $X(V)$ I can produce an element of $X(U)$" doesn't tell you that I have a map from $X(V)$ to $X(U)$ I don't know what I can say.

Comment: @mercio Edited. My question was why we couldn't "from element of $X(U)$ produce an element of $X(V)$. But now that I thought about it diagramatically I think we really can't do that unless $f: U \to V$ is invertible.

Comment: Precomposing is contravariant. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebraically, your quote already tells you what's going on: if you start with $V \to X$, then you can produce $U \to X$. Therefore you get a function $\hom(V, X) \to \hom(U,X)$.

---

The 'reference' example here is the notion of restricting a function. For example, let $C(X)$ be the (contravariant) functor of continuous, real-valued functions on $X$.

If $f$ is a continuous function on $X$ and $S \to X$ is the inclusion of a subspace, then you can form the restriction $f|_S$, which is a continuous function on $S$. This defines an operation $C(X) \to C(S)$.

(in fact, this operation is the value of $C$ at the inclusion arrow)

Comment: Oh, I think I got it, that reference example helped me to clarify that. Thanks!